# Google Analytics Event Tracking Troubleshooting

Tags: google-analytics

I'm struggling with getting a result from my event tracking code... What component(s) are missing in the snippet? Thanks!

```
<a onClick="ga('send', { hittype: 'event',  eventCategory: 'Referral', eventAction: 'Visit Site ', eventLabel: 'Client Name'});"href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

Comment: What issues are you detecting? There's nothing wrong syntactically about the code. Install GA Debugger for Chrome and see if the hit is coming through. You need to wait at least 24 hours for event data to show up in your standard reports. Alternatively, you could check real-time.

Comment: I'm testing it on the real time reporting and I'm not seeing it fire. So if it's not syntax, what other causes could be preventing it from registering the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I see the error. You've got `hittype`, when it should be `hitType`. (I ran it several times in my console but didn't see the hit come through.)

Alternatively, you can use the shorthand syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play','Fall Campaign')
```